# r efficient way to calculate the difference between rows

Tags: r, dplyr, apply

Considering this is my dataset below

```
 Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
          5.7         2.5          5.0         2.0  virginica
          7.7         3.0          6.1         2.3  virginica
          6.7         3.3          5.7         2.1  virginica
          4.8         3.0          1.4         0.1     setosa
          5.5         4.2          1.4         0.2     setosa
          4.9         3.6          1.4         0.1     setosa
          6.3         3.3          4.7         1.6 versicolor
          5.6         2.9          3.6         1.3 versicolor
          5.9         3.0          4.2         1.5 versicolor


df <- structure(list(Sepal.Length = c(5.7, 7.7, 6.7, 4.8, 5.5, 4.9, 
    6.3, 5.6, 5.9), Sepal.Width = c(2.5, 3, 3.3, 3, 4.2, 3.6, 3.3, 
    2.9, 3), Petal.Length = c(5, 6.1, 5.7, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 4.7, 3.6, 
    4.2), Petal.Width = c(2, 2.3, 2.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 1.6, 1.3, 1.5
    ), Species = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("setosa", 
    "versicolor", "virginica"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
    -9L), class = "data.frame")
```

My goal is to

1. Subtract the values of `Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width` from the 1st row of Species == "virginica" with every row of "Setosa",

   Which I am doing like this below

   ```
   Virginia1_vs_Setosa1a <- df[1:4][df$Species == "virginica",][1,] - df[1:4][df$Species == "setosa",][1,]
   Virginia1_vs_Setosa1a 
       0.9        -0.5          3.6         1.9
   Virginia1_vs_Setosa2a <- df[1:4][df$Species == "virginica",][1,] - df[1:4][df$Species == "setosa",][2,]
   Virginia1_vs_Setosa2a
       0.2        -1.7          3.6         1.8
   Virginia1_vs_Setosa3a <- df[1:4][df$Species == "virginica",][1,] - df[1:4][df$Species == "setosa",][3,]
   Virginia1_vs_Setosa3a
       0.8        -1.1          3.6         1.9
   ```
2. Take the product of each element

   ```
     Virginia1_vs_Setosa1 <-  as.numeric(
                        Virginia1_vs_Setosa1a[1]*Virginia1_vs_Setosa1a[2]*
                         Virginia1_vs_Setosa1a[3]*Virginia1_vs_Setosa1a[4])
                         0.9*-0.5*3.6*1.9 = -3.078
     Virginia1_vs_Setosa2  <- as.numeric(
                        Virginia1_vs_Setosa2a[1]*Virginia1_vs_Setosa2a[2]*
                         Virginia1_vs_Setosa2a[3]*Virginia1_vs_Setosa2a[4])
                         0.2*-1.7*3.6*1.8 = -2.2032
     Virginia1_vs_Setosa3  <- as.numeric(
                        Virginia1_vs_Setosa3a[1]*Virginia1_vs_Setosa3a[2]*
                         Virginia1_vs_Setosa3a[3]*Virginia1_vs_Setosa3a[4])
                         0.8*-1.1*3.6*1.9 = -6.0192
   ```

Similarly for the 2nd row in virginica with every row in setosa.

```
      Virginia2_vs_Setosa1a <- df[1:4][df$Species == "virginica",][2,] - df[1:4][df$Species == "setosa",][1,]

      Virginia2_vs_Setosa2a <- df[1:4][df$Species == "virginica",][2,] - df[1:4][df$Species == "setosa",][2,]

      Virginia2_vs_Setosa3a <-  df[1:4][df$Species == "virginica",][2,] - df[1:4][df$Species == "setosa",][3,]

      Virginia2_vs_Setosa1 <-  as.numeric(
              Virginia2_vs_Setosa1a[1]*Virginia2_vs_Setosa1a[2]*
              Virginia2_vs_Setosa1a[3]*Virginia2_vs_Setosa1a[4])

      Virginia2_vs_Setosa2  <- as.numeric(
              Virginia2_vs_Setosa2a[1]*Virginia2_vs_Setosa2a[2]*
              Virginia2_vs_Setosa2a[3]*Virginia2_vs_Setosa2a[4])

      Virginia2_vs_Setosa3  <- as.numeric(
              Virginia2_vs_Setosa3a[1]*Virginia2_vs_Setosa3a[2]*
              Virginia2_vs_Setosa3a[3]*Virginia2_vs_Setosa3a[4])

              rm(Virginia2_vs_Setosa1a, Virginia2_vs_Setosa2a, 
              Virginia2_vs_Setosa3a)
```

Similarly with 3rd row in  virginica with every row in setosa

```
       Virginia3_vs_Setosa1a <- df[1:4][df$Species == "virginica",][3,] - df[1:4][df$Species == "setosa",][1,]

       Virginia3_vs_Setosa2a <- df[1:4][df$Species == "virginica",][3,] - df[1:4][df$Species == "setosa",][2,]

       Virginia3_vs_Setosa3a <-  df[1:4][df$Species == "virginica",][3,] - df[1:4][df$Species == "setosa",][3,]

       Virginia3_vs_Setosa1 <-  as.numeric(
                 Virginia3_vs_Setosa1a[1]*Virginia3_vs_Setosa1a[2]*
                 Virginia3_vs_Setosa1a[3]*Virginia3_vs_Setosa1a[4])

       Virginia3_vs_Setosa2  <- as.numeric(
                 Virginia3_vs_Setosa2a[1]*Virginia3_vs_Setosa2a[2]*
                 Virginia3_vs_Setosa2a[3]*Virginia3_vs_Setosa2a[4])


       Virginia3_vs_Setosa3  <- as.numeric(
                 Virginia3_vs_Setosa3a[1]*Virginia3_vs_Setosa3a[2]*
                 Virginia3_vs_Setosa3a[3]*Virginia3_vs_Setosa3a[4])

         rm(Virginia3_vs_Setosa1a, Virginia3_vs_Setosa2a, 
            Virginia3_vs_Setosa3a)
```

And finally creating a 3*3 matrix like this below

```
matrix(c(Virginia1_vs_Setosa1, Virginia1_vs_Setosa2, Virginia1_vs_Setosa3, Virginia2_vs_Setosa1, Virginia2_vs_Setosa2, Virginia2_vs_Setosa3,
  Virginia3_vs_Setosa1, Virginia3_vs_Setosa2, Virginia3_vs_Setosa3), nrow=3, ncol=3)


       [,1]     [,2]    [,3]
[1,] -3.0780   0.0000  4.9020
[2,] -2.2032 -26.0568 -8.8236
[3,] -6.0192 -17.3712 -4.6440
```

As you can see my solution is very clunky and inefficient. I will be very thankful if anybody can show me an efficient way of achieving the same results.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a double `for` loop. Maybe there are solutions with the `*apply` family of functions but this one works.

```
f <- droplevels(df$Species[df$Species != "versicolor"])
sp <- split(df[df$Species != "versicolor", ], f)

res <- matrix(0, 3, 3)
for(i in 1:nrow(sp[[1]])){
  for(j in 1:nrow(sp[[2]])){
    res[i, j] <- prod(sp[[2]][j, -5] - sp[[1]][i, -5])
  }
}

res
#        [,1]     [,2]    [,3]
#[1,] -3.0780   0.0000  4.9020
#[2,] -2.2032 -26.0568 -8.8236
#[3,] -6.0192 -17.3712 -4.6440
```

Answer (score 0):

For this particular case, you can borrow some ideas from `outer`

```
X <- lapply(split(df[df$Species=="virginica", 1:4], 1:3), unlist)
Y <- lapply(split(df[df$Species=="setosa", 1:4], 1:3), unlist)

FUN <- function(l1, l2) mapply(function(v,w) prod(v-w), l1, l2)
Y <- rep(Y, rep.int(length(X), length(Y)))
if (length(X)) 
    X <- rep(X, times = ceiling(length(Y)/length(X)))
matrix(FUN(X, Y), ncol=3L, byrow=TRUE)
```

For the most general case, you will need to generate every possible pairs of different rows, then calculate according to your formula. Using `data.table`, it would be something like:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
setorder(df, Species)[, numid := rowid(Species)]

parts <- split(df, by=c("Species", "numid"))
combis <- CJ(parts, parts, sorted=FALSE)
combis[, .(
        Species1=V1[[1]][,Species], 
        numid1=V1[[1]][,numid],
        Species2=V2[[1]][,Species], 
        numid2=V2[[1]][,numid],
        differ=prod(V1[[1]][, 1:4] - V2[[1]][, 1:4])), 
    by=seq_len(combis[,.N])][
        Species1!=Species2, -1L]
```